# Swift, SceneKit and camera position

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnscene, scncamera

I'm developing an app showing a 3D human body - in the SceneKit editor, I've set up the camera pointing to the model.

As I did set *sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true*, the user can move around the object, zoom in and zoom out with simple gestures.

In order to move vertically, I've implemented an UISlider - I don't want the user to pan vertically with two finger gestures.

In the slider action, I do the following:

```
@IBAction func sliderDidMove(_ sender: UISlider) {
    cameraNode = sceneView.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "camera", recursively: true)
    let vert = 1.5*(0.5 - sender.value)
    cameraNode?.position.y = posY + vert
}
```

This works fine when I change the slider position just after loading my ViewController. But as soon as I rotate or zoom the model by gestures, the slider no longer shows effect - thus I can no longer change the position of my camera node programmatically.

Has anyone an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (it's been a while since I've placed with SK) you can't do both... once AllowsCamera is actually used the Scene ignores other inputs. You may have to take over all control - don't be worried about that, its not difficult.

Comment: You may also want to try using sceneView.pointOfView in case it turns up a different result from the node named "camera". It's been a while since I used SceneKit with a SCNView, but I remember some confusion with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dennis - I tried it out and it works! And so simple!

@IBAction func sliderDidMove(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let vert = 1.1*(0.5 - sender.value)
        sceneView.pointOfView?.position.y = posY + vert
    }